# Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade fetch api - AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, referrer-policy

I have created API using AWS API gateway and while creating individual GET call selected **"Use Lambda Proxy integration"**, and allow cors on that resource.
But after publishing API its works fine I am able to get a response in postman/firefox. 
But when I  used the same API with fetch method then in Chrome it is throwing
"Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade" but the same code is working fine with firefox.

sample code : 
const response1 = await fetch("https://33222321.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/get-activejobs")
Error in console 
Request URL: https://33222321.execute-api.us-east-.amazonaws.com/dev/getarchivedjobs
**Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade**

I tried to pass some parameters in fetch combination from here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/ is there any setting I am missing?

The same API works fine if I change with Proxy integration. 
the expected output is the JSON response from that API.

Comment: _“Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade”_ - is that supposed to be the _full_ “error” message?

Comment: No there is no error message, I am expecting JSON response if error that is also part of JSON.

Comment: You’re not making much sense here. First you say, Chrome was “throwing” something, now you say there is no error at all. So, no clue what the actual _problem_ is even supposed to be here now. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question, so that it contains a _proper_ problem description.

Comment: OK, Chrome is throwing error message and this is related to CHROME only, for FF it is working as expected. I have enabled CORS for my API. Still showing "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade" - this is my problem

Comment: `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade` _on its own_ is not an actual error.

Comment: (Plus, `no-referrer-when-downgrade` means no referrer will be send if there is a _downgrade_ in protocols. Since the address you are making the request _to_ is an HTTPS one, that does not even apply here.)

Comment: yes, after reading some documents on AWS, I am also a bit confused but I am getting this only on chrome browser, why this is showing and this is only if I select proxy lambda Proxy integration case only.

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem is solved, Following is workaround. 
 return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps({"data": response}),
             "headers": {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                "Allow" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*"
            }
        }

Comment: was this ever resolved? seeing same issue with S3 ?